# Filter list of objects based on list of object properties

Tags: kotlin, collections

What is the best way to filter out a list of objects with a list of properties of the given object.

Here is the sample code that shows what I'm trying to achieve:

```
    data class Person(
            val id: Long = 0,
            val name: String = ""
    )

    fun filterOutList(): List<Person>{

        val idsToRemove = listOf(1, 3)

        val listToFilter = listOf(
                Person(1, "John"),
                Person(2, "Jane"),
                Person(3, "Bob"),
                Person(4, "Nick")
        )

        // expecting to get a list only with Objects that have ids 2 and 4

        return listToFilter.filter { ??? provide `idsToRemove` to get only what was not in the list  }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it this way: `return listToFilter.filter { it.id !in idsToRemove }`.

To get it compiled, you should explicitly specify the `<Long>` type parameter when you create `idsToRemove`: `listOf<Long>(1, 3)` or `listOf(1L, 3L)`. The compiler infers the `<Int>` type parameter implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use native method `filter{ }`.
As following:

```
return listOf(
                Person(1, "John"),
                Person(2, "Jane"),
                Person(3, "Bob"),
                Person(4, "Nick")
        ).filter{ it.id == 2 || it.id == 4 }
```

Comment: This is kinda hard coding. What if `idsToRemove` is a dynamic array?

Answer (score 0):

I found following solution that worked for me:

```
val filteredResponse = listToFilter.filter { ! idsToRemove.contains(it.id) }
```

But as @Bananon mentioned, I had to explicitly specify `idsToRemove: listOf<Long>(1, 3)`